# In ReSharper 7, how do I skip unit tests marked with multiple categories?

Tags: unit-testing, resharper, categories, resharper-7.1

I have searched the R# documentation and the R# community at JetBrains, as well as here, but I haven't found an answer.

I have something like this: an assembly marked with an Acceptance category. Some of those tests are also *individually* marked with a Future category. As I complete those tests, I remove the Future category.

What I would like to do is tell R# 7 to run tests marked with Acceptance unless they are also marked Future.

I added Future into "Skip tests from categories:" on the UnitTesting tab in the options dialog. But when I ran the Acceptance category, and *all tests were run - none were skipped.*

Am I just out of luck? Does running a category override skipping a category?

Thanks,

Jeff